# Call to a member function post() on null on many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have created two table to store post information:

Posts table where I store overall information except categories.

Migration file of each table looks like this:

**posts**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->longText('excerpt');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->tinyInteger('feature')->default(1);
        $table->enum('status',['publish','draft']);
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**post_categories**

```
Schema::create('post_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now, I have following function in PostCategory model:

```
public function post(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

Now, when I try to fetch data using following:

```
\App\Models\PostCategory::find(5)->post()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

I get call to member function post() on null

What should I do to get post with the category 5?

Comment: please add your model code as well

Comment: @KamleshPaul I have included model code.

Comment: You don't need a model for the pivot table in a `many-to-many` relationship... Please re-read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many A `Post` can have many `Category` records, and a `Category` can have many `Post` records, but you don't access this via the intermediate table. Use the proper `belongsToMany` on each model.

Comment: @TimLewis How can I get the expected answer. I hope I have made my question clear. If not please let me know what I have to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is clear, and my comment is that you've got the relationship defined completely wrong. That's the answer; fix your relationship as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood some concepts.

Here your relationship is between **post** and **categories**.

In **post Model**

```
public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'post_categories','post_id','category_id');
}
```

In the **Category model**

```
public function posts(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'post_categories','category_id','post_id');
}
```

Now, You're free to access posts from category and categories from post.

```
$post = Post::with('categories')->where('id',5)->first();
```

By this, you'll get a post with its categories.

```
$category= Category::with('posts')->where('id',5)->first();
```

By this, you'll get category with its posts.

Check more detail how [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) work

**Edit:-**

If by using post you want to make a condition in the categories then.

```
$post = Post::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function($q){
    $q->where('id',5);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to get all post with category 5 so I did `Post::with('categories')->where('id',5)->get();` it only return one. Maybe, it fetch post with id 5 and category id 5. Is it?

Comment: `$category= Category::with('posts')->where('id',5)->first();` this one will return your result.

Comment: Do I have to define the code in PostCategory model that you have said to define in Category Model? expected Or is it in the Category model itself because I am not getting expected answer. By calling this `Post::with('categories')->where('id',5)->first(); ` I am getting post with id 5 and by accessing this `Category::with('posts')->where('id',5)->first();` I get the data of category id 5 like `category name, category id and so on`

Comment: have you made a function in the model? `Category::with('posts')` with this you'll get category(no = 5) + post that belongs to (no = 5)

Comment: Yes, I have made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209451/discussion-between-alisha-lamichhane-and-dilip-hirapara).